# Mousedown event not working correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", myFunction, false);
function myFunction(event){   
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;
  alert(x+","+y);
}
```

In Chrome, x and y are coordinates representing the click. In Firefox, both are undefined.

Why is that, and what should I be using instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/mousedown

You can see the parameters will be clientX / clientY.